# Live streaming with Jquery image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

I am having a situation like how can I run a slideshow as live streaming. Like if I have two screen at a time and both having same page of image slider opens in the browser and when I click on the next or previous button slide will change on both the screen simultaneously. Is there any way to do that, If then please give me any suggestion how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to to send the "Slide change" event to the server and from there push it to all the clients. I suggest you look on https://www.firebase.com/ they have good tutorials on this.

The final code will be something like:

```
myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    var message = snapshot.val();

    currentSlide = message.currentSlide
    changeSlide(currentSlide)
});


var sendToServer = function(newSlide) {
    myDataRef.push({
        currentSlide(newSlide)
    });   
}

$('.slider .slide-right').on('click', function() {
    var newIndex = //here you set the new slider index (for example "1" for the first image
   sendToServer(newIndex) //here you send the index of the new selected image to the server which will then send it to all the clients
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you response any example related to slideshow in this I didn't find any think related to this.

Comment: Could you please paste the same example on jsfiddle.net. So I have clear idea what it exactly do.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/9Ynuy/
You need to create an account on firebase, right now it's using mine. All that is left to do is the actual slideshow, set the image to show in the "this.changeSliderState" function and you're good to go

Comment: I try to go to https://slideshow-example.firebaseIO.com/ link but it is not authorized. Also when I try the above code it shows me error that firebase is not defined , I am new to this and i don't have any idea what I need to do.

Comment: you don't have access to slidesho-example.firebaseIO.com because that I created that. You need to go to firebase.com and create you own account there. Basically they will set up a server that will synchronize all your clients. Follow theyre chat tutorial and you'll understand.

Comment: Could you please give any example for the image slider to same think so it would be better. I am new to jquery so I am not able to figure out how can I integrate any of image slider with it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,I am looking at it surely accept your answer in some time.

Comment: There is only one problem if current slide is 0 and if you click on minus button then blank will show with index -1 which should be 2.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the problem but I thought it's out of the question's scope, anyway, here's a version that fixes it: http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/9Ynuy/3/

Comment: What do you need it for? I was thinking, right now, every user can control everyone else's slider. If you want to be able to control everyone else's slider you might need to have two different pages, one (password protected) that sets the current Image and one for the clients to display the images. This would be the easies solution. Otherwise you can opt for a server side language and on the client do continuous updates to see what the current image is (uglier solution imho).

Comment: Is there any way to create that reference link dynamically through php or is there any API for it. I need to create `https://slideshow-example.firebaseIO.com/` link dynamically where `slideshow-example` that name will be generate by randomly. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I don't know, try looking in the docs on firebase.com, but I doubt it.. you might need to set up your own web socket

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have solved my problem do it in other way.. :)